# i get 'com.facebook.jni.CppException: Could not get BatchedBridge, make sure your bundle is packaged correctly...' error from react native signed apk

Tags: android, react-native

```
com.facebook.jni.CppException: Could not get BatchedBridge, make sure your bundle is packaged correctly
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:29)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:232)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

this the error that i get from android studio logcat also from my phone bug report screen.
 this error happened when i published app in play store and its ok when i install it directly from terminal with react-native run-android --variant=release

react-native version: 0.60.4
enableHermes: true

Comment: I'm also having this problem. My crashlytics is spitting out the same error and my app is still on 'Processing update' in google play console for 2 days now. Did you find any solutions on this?

Comment: i just disabled hermes and error disappeared

Comment: @ChristilynArjona did you find a fix for this?

Comment: @Newoda I just changed my app package to .apk instead of an app bundle (.aab) and that worked for me